# New operator crash

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have a crash with signal 6 aborted on new operator with the following callstack:

```
> #0  0x00f6d00b in __kernel_vsyscall ()
> #1  0x009fdbaa in ____strtoull_l_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #2  0x009ff44a in ____strtof_l_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #3  0x00a3bbb5 in _IO_default_pbackfail_internal () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #4  0x00a46671 in memalign () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #5  0x00a4235f in _obstack_newchunk () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #6  0x00a4334e in strverscmp () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #7  0x083d54cd in operator new (size=1160) at /home/build/exp.cpp:8145
> #8  .............
```

What are the possible reasons I can end up with this? The memory usage of my machine is quite low, about 8% of 12GB, I don't think memory is an issue ( the core dump is about 700MB ).

The new operator is overloaded to use malloc:

```
void * operator new (size_t size) throw()
{
 return malloc(size);
}
```

Comment: what are you creating with `new`?

Comment: Something like 90% of all `new` crashes are due to heap corruption caused by previous errors. How safe is your code?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I used valgrind in the hope I will see the problem again, but didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely overrun an new'd/malloc'ed block earlier, destroying the book-keeping data malloc uses, hence it crashes the next time you try to malloc something.

Answer (score 2):

You should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) then use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Your implementation of `new` is wrong. `malloc` can fail, and in that case your `new` should throw an exception. It is not allowed to return `NULL`

If your GCC is recent, consider also using `-fsanitize=address`